# How to vertically align an AdSense fixed ad unit?

Tags: css, ads, adsense

I'm using a fixed size ad unit from AdSense.

I'm placing it inside my container `div`, which defines the `width` and `height` for the ad.

**CASE 1: Sometimes it makes smart decisions like this:**

[image]

**CASE 2: But sometimes it chooses to render an ad with a smaller height (than the container div):**

[image]

In this **CASE 2**, how can I make it vertically aligned in the center of my container?

Here's my ad code:

```
<AdContainer_DIV>
  <ins className="adsbygoogle"
    style={{display:"inline-block", width:"100%", height: "100%"}}
    data-ad-client="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    data-adtest="on"
  >
  </ins>
</AdContainer_DIV>
```

The problem is that this is what gets rendered out of that code:

```
> <AdContainer_DIV>      // THIS IS IN MY CODE
>>  <ins>                // THIS IS IN MY CODE (FROM THIS POINT, EVERYTHING BELOW IS CREATED BY ADSENSE)
>>>   <ins>              // THIS HAS 100% HEIGHT OF MY CONTAINER
>>>>    <ins>            // THIS HAS 100% HEIGHT OF MY CONTAINER
>>>>>     <iframe>       // THIS HAS 100% HEIGHT OF MY CONTAINER
>>>>>>      <iframe>     // THIS HAS 100% HEIGHT OF MY CONTAINER
>>>>>>>       <body>     // THIS HAS 100% HEIGHT OF MY CONTAINER
>>>>>>>>        <div>    // THIS THE ACTUAL AD WITH THE SMALLER HEIGHT
```

I don't think I can do it with CSS. There's got to be some AdSense tag that should do this trick. Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-YLGeXaapI0/5IgZopewRJcFXomhRMlYYjugPLSyNjTY=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>
<body>

<style>
.verticalhorizontal{
 display: table-cell;
 height: 150px;
 width: 300px;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
  
  border-style: solid;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
 <div class="verticalhorizontal">
  <div style="background-color: red;">Your Add Code</div>
 </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't think this could work, because it's all inside iframes, and you can't style an iframe unless it allows CORS. I really needed some programatic tag from AdSense to do this trick. But I don't think there is one. Thanks, though.